# Maintaining same session after browser closes and reopens

Tags: asp.net, session

I am new to asp.net. I login the site and created session for userid consider this session as s1.
Add an cookie (c1) to client site with expiration of 3 days is added.

Suppose if i close the browser without logout and again i use the same url then i found session is null but i got cookie (c1) then i created a new session. But session s1 is still occupies memory on server.  Means this time two sessions are on the same server occupying memory.

I want to use session s1 with the cookie (c1) - is it possible. or i want to delete session s1 if second time the request comes.

The code I used is:

```
 if (Session["UserInfo"] != null)
    {
      // code 
    }
    else
    {
        HttpCookie HT = Request.Cookies["User"];
        if (HT != null)
        {
           Session["UserInfo"] = HT["UserName"]; //Here new session is created while previous is already exist on server
        }
        else
        {
           //code
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What kind of session you are using (InProc, Sql, State service)? Are you sure the cookie you are talking about is session-related, not authentication cookie? Usually you set up session server-side timeout and the client-side cookie expires at browser close.

Comment: i am using inproc session .here i am explicitaly creating cookies for next time login and  i want to reuse the server memory because session is already created on server why should i create new session again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE generate a new session id on each request. So when u close your browser old Session id is get lost, so browser sends request with new session id. That's why u are not able to get value of session.

But on server it occupies server memory , which is cleared by server after session time out.

Firefox sends request with same session id on each request, u can get your session Id even if u close your browser tab.

Comment: Session IDs are created by the server, not the client (browser).

Comment: concept of session is completely server side.

Answer (score 0):

Typical ASP configuration cookie with Forms Authentication:

.ASPXFORMSAUTH expires: 30 min
ASP.NET_SessionId expires: At end of session

So when you close your browser, you will loose session but you won't be logged off.
When you reopen browser only ASP.NET_SessionId is expired.

If you want to create persistent session cookies use this:

[Create Persistent ID Cookies](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/security-development/create-persistent-id-cookies)